# What is the table where Oracle Apex stores its errors that happen when an app is running

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When I am running an Oracle Apex app in Debug Mode, then a black bar shows at the bottom of each page.

One of the links of that black bar is Session, where you can see the values of various session variables and other stuff.
In that Session window, the last tab is errors -> that shows the errors encountered by each user for each page.

In which table are those error messages stored. They are shown in an interactive report - so I think that they are being captured in some Oracle table.

Comment: Also note you can install the application builder applications in your own workspace, if you want to look under the hood. These apps are located in the /builder folder of the Oracle APEX download zip, and you can identify the relevant app from the builder URL.

Answer (score 4):

It's apex_debug_messages. There are a couple of good blogs on this - just google it. It's important to know that this is a view that only shows data in an apex context, so you'll have to create an apex session `apex_session.create_session` in order to see any data.